# PHP Pagination with range

Tags: php, ajax, pagination

I've a pagination script and it is working fine. I want to add a range to my pagination. BUt it should be in the following format;

<< < 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 > >>

When I click on "5", then it should be;

<< < 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 > >>

Similarly when click on "8", then it should be;

<< < 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 > >>

Suppose "11" is the last page and if we click on 11, it should be;

<< < 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 > >>

My code is look like this;

```
    $recordLimit = 4;

    $totalNumberofRecords = 100;

    $currentpage = !empty( $startPage ) ? (int) $startPage : 1 ;

    $startFrom = ( $currentpage -1 ) * $recordLimit;

    $limit =  $startFrom.','.$recordLimit;

    $totalPages = ceil( $totalNumberOfRecords / $recordLimit );

    $j = 0;

    for ($i = max(1, $currentpage - 1); $i<= min($currentpage + 4, $totalPages); $i++) {

 $fairLists['pages'][$j] = $i;

if ( $startPage == $fairLists['pages'][$j] ||  ( $j == 0 && empty( $startPage ) ) 
   {
    $fairLists['pages'][$j] = array( $i ,"font-weight:bold;");
}else{
    $fairLists['pages'][$j] = array( $i , 'font-weight:normal;' );
}
$j++;
```

}

I want to limit the range to 5, and when we reach the range, it should display 1 previous record and 3 next records;

If somebody knows the script, then please help me,

Thanks,

Arun

Answer (score 0):

your problem is solved by me.. My code is as under but after using this code if it works for you then please hit this comment as an answer.....
Code is as

```
<php
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$recordsPerPage = 10;
$fromRecordNum = ($recordsPerPage * $page) - $recordsPerPage;

$query = "SELECT * FROM
        table_mstr_department
        ORDER BY DeptId
      LIMIT 
        {$fromRecordNum}, {$recordsPerPage}";


  $stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
  $stmt->execute();
  $num = $stmt->rowCount();


  echo "<div id='search_area'>";
        echo "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td colspan='3'></td>";
                echo "</tr>";

                echo "<tr>";
                //********Add New Department Button
                    echo "<td  height='auto' width='auto'>";
                        echo "<input type='submit' name='newemp' value='Add New Department'>";
                     echo "</td>";
                    echo  "<td width='auto'></td>";

                    //******Search Button
                    echo "<td width='auto'>";
                            echo "<div id='search_options'>";
                                    echo "<input type='search' name='search_text'  width='auto' style='height:20px;'/>";
                                    echo "<input type='button' name='search_btn' value='Search' />";
                            echo "</div>";
                    echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td  height='auto' width='auto'>";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo  "<td width='auto'></td>";
                    echo "<td width='auto'>";
                        echo "<div id='search_options'>";
                        echo "</td>";
        echo  "</tr>";

    echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";

 if($num>0)
 {

    echo '<table width="100%" id="dep_table"  style="margin-top:10px;"  cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" border="0">';
    echo '<tr bgcolor="#4682B4">';
    echo '<th>Editor</th>';
    echo '<th>Department Id</th>';
    echo '<th>Department Name</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    $i=0;


    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $i++;
        if($i % 2 == 0) 
        {
            $bgcolor= "#6AA2C3";
        }
        else 
        {
         $bgcolor= "#A2B5CD";
        }
        //extract row, this will make $row['firstname'] to just $firstname only
        extract($row);

        //creating new table row per record
        echo "<tr bgcolor='$bgcolor' id='$DeptId' name='edit_tr'>";
    echo '<td id="edit"><input id="edit" type="radio" name="deptid" value="DeptId" ?></td>';

    echo "<td class='format'>{$row['DeptId']}</td>";
    echo "<td class='format'>{$row['DeptName']}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }


    echo "</table>";
 }




 echo "</div>";
```

//******************************************************************************************

```
 echo "<div id='nav_position'>";
    if($page>1)
    {
        // ********** show the first page
        echo "<a href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "' title='Go to the first page.' class='customBtn'>";
            echo "<span style='margin:0 .5em;'> << </span>";
        echo "</a>";

        // ********** show the previous page
        $prev_page = $page - 1;
        echo "<a href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?page={$prev_page}' title='Previous page is {$prev_page}.' class='customBtn'>";
            echo "<span style='margin:0 .5em;'> < </span>";
        echo "</a>";

    }


    // ********** show the number paging

    // find out total pages
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total_rows FROM table_mstr_department";
    $stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute();

    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $total_rows = $row['total_rows'];

    $total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $recordsPerPage);

    // range of num links to show
    $range = 2;

    // display links to 'range of pages' around 'current page'
    $initial_num = $page - $range;
    $condition_limit_num = ($page + $range)  + 1;

    for ($x=$initial_num; $x<$condition_limit_num; $x++) 
    {

        // be sure '$x is greater than 0' AND 'less than or equal to the $total_pages'
        if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $total_pages)) 
        {

            // current page
            if ($x == $page) 
            {
                echo "<span class='customBtn' style='background:#0D6598;'>$x</span>";
            } 

            // not current page
            else 
            {
                echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$x' class='customBtn'>$x</a> ";
            }
        }
    }


    // ***** for 'next' and 'last' pages
    if($page<$total_pages)
    {
        // ********** show the next page
        $next_page = $page + 1;
        echo "<a href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?page={$next_page}' title='Next page is {$next_page}.' class='customBtn'>";
            echo "<span style='margin:0 .5em;'> > </span>";
        echo "</a>";

        // ********** show the last page
        echo "<a href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?page={$total_pages}' title='Last page is {$total_pages}.' class='customBtn'>";
            echo "<span style='margin:0 .5em;'> >> </span>";
        echo "</a>";
    }

    /*
    echo "<input type='text' name='page' size='1' />";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='Go_btn' value='Go' class='customBtn' />";<?php */

echo "</div>";
?>
```

You can modify this code accordingly. This code displays three columns...
   Best of luck..... and do not forgot to like this as an asnwer

Comment: At least you should reply for yes or no

Comment: Can you please illustrate this with my example ?

Comment: $recordLimit = 4;

    $totalNumberofRecords = 100;

    $currentpage = !empty( $startPage ) ? (int) $startPage : 1 ;

    $startFrom = ( $currentpage -1 ) * $recordLimit;

    $limit =  $startFrom.','.$recordLimit;

    $totalPages = ceil( $totalNumberOfRecords / $recordLimit );

    $j = 0;
   Upto this, your code is okay.. but after this there is no logic in your code

Comment: Sorry, In my requirement, pagination is working properly with out any issues. I just want the limit in the specified manner. If possible just give me a hint. Otherwise leave it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "<div id='nav_position'>";
if($page>1)
{
    // ********** show the first page
    echo "<a href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "' title='Go to the first page.' class='customBtn'>";
        echo "<span style='margin:0 .5em;'> << </span>";
    echo "</a>";

    // ********** show the previous page
    $prev_page = $page - 1;
    echo "<a href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?page={$prev_page}' title='Previous page is {$prev_page}.' class='customBtn'>";
        echo "<span style='margin:0 .5em;'> < </span>";
    echo "</a>";

}


// ********** show the number paging

// find out total pages
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total_rows FROM table_mstr_department";
$stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total_rows = $row['total_rows'];

$total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $recordsPerPage);

// range of num links to show
$range = 2;

// display links to 'range of pages' around 'current page'
$initial_num = $page - $range;
$condition_limit_num = ($page + $range)  + 1;

for ($x=$initial_num; $x<$condition_limit_num; $x++) 
{

    // be sure '$x is greater than 0' AND 'less than or equal to the $total_pages'
    if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $total_pages)) 
    {

        // current page
        if ($x == $page) 
        {
            echo "<span class='customBtn' style='background:#0D6598;'>$x</span>";
        } 

        // not current page
        else 
        {
            echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$x' class='customBtn'>$x</a> ";
        }
    }
}


// ***** for 'next' and 'last' pages
if($page<$total_pages)
{
    // ********** show the next page
    $next_page = $page + 1;
    echo "<a href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?page={$next_page}' title='Next page is {$next_page}.' class='customBtn'>";
        echo "<span style='margin:0 .5em;'> > </span>";
    echo "</a>";

    // ********** show the last page
    echo "<a href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?page={$total_pages}' title='Last page is {$total_pages}.' class='customBtn'>";
        echo "<span style='margin:0 .5em;'> >> </span>";
    echo "</a>";
}

/*
echo "<input type='text' name='page' size='1' />";
echo "<input type='submit' name='Go_btn' value='Go' class='customBtn' />";<?php */

echo "</div>";
```

Comment: You can use this code. It will give range your buttons aas a google page search button at the end of google site

Comment: Sorry, this is not I expected !!..I need the functionality in the same format I described in the question.